# "X11/Xlib.h": no such file or directory on mac os x mountain lion

Tags: c, x11, osx-mountain-lion

I came across this when I was compiling a simple program:

```
 #include <X11/Xlib.h>
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>

 Display* display;

 int main(){
     display = XOpenDisplay("");
     if (display == NULL) {
         printf("Cannot connect\n");
         exit (-1);
     }
     else{
         printf("Success!\n");
         XCloseDisplay(display);
     }
  }
```

FYI, I have xQuartz installed.
I compile this program with "g++ -o ex ex.cpp -L/usr/X11R6/lib -lX11" command.

Comment: Does xQuartz come with headers? You might need to install those separately.

Comment: Did you install the 'command line tools' package for XCode?  The headers in `/usr/include/X11` may well be distributed with that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

you need to compile with:

```
g++ -o ex ex.cpp -I/usr/X11R6/include -L/usr/X11R6/lib -lX11
```

the `X11` headers are installed with `xQuartz`, but you need to reference them explicitly

If you install `xQuartz` it installs into `/opt/X11`, and `/usr/X11` and `/usr/X11R6` are symlinks to this location

Answer (score 25):

You may need to add symbolic link to X11 folder by:

> sudo ln -s /opt/X11/include/X11 /usr/local/include/X11

In my case, I had to make include directory under `usr/local`.

Comment: Awesome! This did it for me. Thanks for posting.

Answer (score 2):

This solution worked for me for ruby-1.9.3-p362 on Mavericks.

```
sudo ln -s /opt/X11/include/X11 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/usr/include/
```