# install x11 in mac 10.10.1

Tags: macos, x11

I am trying to run a program in this system.

There is a makefile in the package. And I also need X11 to run it, so I have installed xQuarts,and add all the (potentially) useful path to the PATH.

when I type "$PATH" in the terminal, 
it shows:

```
-bash:
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin: No such file or directory
```

I used "make all" in my source code package, it result in the following error:

```
./Xlibext.c:2:10: fatal error: 'X11/Xlib.h' file not found
#include "X11/Xlib.h"
         ^
1 error generated.
```

I have reviewed some other posts, but I couldn't find a solution yet. Can anyone help?

Comment: possible duplicate of ["X11/Xlib.h": no such file or directory on mac os x mountain lion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14321038/x11-xlib-h-no-such-file-or-directory-on-mac-os-x-mountain-lion)

Comment: Yes, it is. I didn't notice there is a solution on 2nd floor. Thank you!